# Getting ERROR 1701, ERROR 1452 and ERROR 1305 errors in MySQL - Need some expertise

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1452, mysql-error-1071

This is my first real crack at making a database in Third Normal Form. I managed to create the DDL script ok (I had the logical model verified to 3NF before I went ahead and built the script) but I get a whole lot of errors I am unsure of fixing. I may have bitten more than I can chew for this particular case but I don't want to give up - it's a big learning curve for me and with some help I can get past this and move on.

First of all, here is my DDL script:

```
-- This sql script creates the structure.
-- of the rugby club database.

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS database_rugby;

CREATE DATABASE database_rugby;

USE database_rugby;

-- Create the "coach" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`coach` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`coach` (
  `coachID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `dateBeganCoaching` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`coachID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "grade" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`grade` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`grade` (
  `gradeID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `gradeName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `minWeight` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `maxWeight` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `minAge` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `maxAge` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `ballSize` INT(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gradeID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "coachQualification" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`coachQualification` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`coachQualification` (
  `qualID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `qualName` CHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  `gradeID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`qualID`) ,
  INDEX `gradeID` (`gradeID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `coachQualification_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gradeID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`grade` (`gradeID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "parent" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`parent` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`parent` (
  `parentID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parentID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "school" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`school` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`school` (
  `schoolID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `schoolName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schoolID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "player" table.
--
-- Inherits fields from the "person"
-- and "school" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`player` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`player` (
  `playerID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `schoolID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`playerID`) ,
  INDEX `schoolID` (`schoolID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `player_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`schoolID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`school` (`schoolID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "person" table.
--
-- This table has one:one relationships
-- with the parent, coach and player 
-- tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`person` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`person` (
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `dateOfBirth` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `streetAddress` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
  `suburbAddress` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `cityAddress` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
  `photo` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `parent_parentID` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `coach_coachID` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `player_playerID` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `parent_parentID1` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `player_playerID1` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `coach_coachID1` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `coach_coachID2` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `parent_parentID2` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `player_playerID2` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`personID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_person_coach1` (`coach_coachID2` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_person_parent1` (`parent_parentID2` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_person_player1` (`player_playerID2` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`coach_coachID2` )
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`coach` (`coachID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_person_parent1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_parentID2`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`parent` (`parentID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_person_player1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`player_playerID2`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`player` (`playerID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "homePhone" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`homePhone` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`homePhone` (
  `homePhoneID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `homeNumber` CHAR(9) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`homePhoneID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "mobilePhone" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`mobilePhone` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`mobilePhone` (
  `mobilePhoneID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `mobileNumber` CHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mobilePhoneID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "emailAddress" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`emailAddress` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`emailAddress` (
  `emailAddressID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `emailAddress` CHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emailAddressID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "Contact" table
--
-- This is a linking table 
-- that describes the many:many 
-- relationships between "person" 
-- and the "homePhone", "mobilePhone", 
-- and "emailAddress" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`contact` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`contact` (
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `homePhoneID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `mobilePhoneID` INT(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `emailAddressID` INT(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  INDEX `personID` (`personID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `homePhoneID` (`homePhoneID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `mobilePhoneID` (`mobilePhoneID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `emailAddressID` (`emailAddressID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `contact_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`personID` )
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`person` (`personID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `contact_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`homePhoneID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`homePhone` (`homePhoneID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `contact_ibfk_3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mobilePhoneID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`mobilePhone` (`mobilePhoneID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `contact_ibfk_4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`emailAddressID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`emailAddress` (`emailAddressID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "family" table.
--
-- This is a linking table 
-- that describes the many:many 
-- relationship between "parent" 
-- and "player" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`family` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`family` (
  `parentID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `playerID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `parent_parentID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `playerID` (`playerID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_family_parent1` (`parent_parentID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `family_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`playerID` )
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`player` (`playerID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_family_parent1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_parentID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`parent` (`parentID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "qualificationSet" table.
--
-- This is a linking table 
-- that describes the many:many 
-- relationship between "coach" 
-- and "coachQualification" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`qualificationSet` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`qualificationSet` (
  `coachID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `qualID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `coachID` (`coachID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `qualID` (`qualID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `qualificationSet_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`coachID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`coach` (`coachID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `qualificationSet_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`qualID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`coachQualification` (`qualID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "team" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`team` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`team` (
  `teamID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `teamName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `teamYear` INT(2) NOT NULL ,
  `gradeID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teamID`) ,
  INDEX `gradeID` (`gradeID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `team_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gradeID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`grade` (`gradeID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "teamAllocation" table
--
-- this is a linking table for a 
-- many:many relationship between
-- team and player tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`teamAllocation` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_rugby`.`teamAllocation` (
  `teamID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `playerID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `teamID` (`teamID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `playerID` (`playerID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `teamallocation_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`teamID` )
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`team` (`teamID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `teamAllocation_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`playerID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`player` (`playerID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "teamCoachAllocation" table.
--
-- This is a linking table 
-- that describes the many:many 
-- relationship between "coach" 
-- and "team" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database_rugby`.`teamCoachAllocation` ;
CREATE TABLE `database_rugby`.`teamCoachAllocation` (
  `coachID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `teamID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `coachID` (`coachID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `teamID` (`teamID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `teamCoachAllocation_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`coachID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`coach` (`coachID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `teamCoachAllocation_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`teamID`)
    REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`team` (`teamID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And here is my DML script (note: so far the script only attempts to insert records in the "person", "school", and "player" details. If the problems I have encountered so far are fixed, this could help me for later on..):

```
-- database_data.sql.
-- This sql script inserts data into the 
-- rugby club database.

USE database_rugby;

TRUNCATE TABLE database_rugby.person;

-- Insert new persons which will be 
-- players.
INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Michael", 
"Peck", 
'2002-12-10',
"45 Skibo Street",
"Caversham", 
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Matt", 
"Petersen", 
'2001-06-15',
"192 Bayview Road",
"South Dunedin", 
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Christopher", 
"Petersen", 
'2003-02-19',
"192 Bayview Road",
"South Dunedin", 
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Richard", 
"Michaels", 
'2002-04-08',
"15 Fitzroy Street",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Shaun", 
"Michaels", 
'2003-11-11',
"15 Fitzroy Street",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Harry", 
"Dackers", 
'2004-02-11',
"32 Peter Street",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Daniel", 
"Mitchell", 
'2002-05-19',
"112 South Road",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

-- Insert new persons which will be 
-- parents.
INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Gregory", 
"Peck", 
'1971-07-22',
"123 Burns Street",
"South Dunedin", 
"Dunedin");


INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Laura", 
"Peck", 
'1979-09-08',
"123 Burns Street",
"South Dunedin", 
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Martha", 
"Petersen", 
'1973-12-07',
"192 Bayview Road",
"South Dunedin", 
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Chris", 
"Michaels", 
'1967-08-07',
"15 Fitzroy Street",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Nadine", 
"Michaels", 
'1973-10-19',
"15 Fitzroy Street",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Barry", 
"Dackers", 
'1965-02-11',
"32 Peter Street",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Kevin", 
"Mitchell", 
'1972-05-19',
"112 South Road",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.person (
firstName,
lastName,
dateOfBirth,
streetAddress,
suburbAddress,
cityAddress)
VALUES(
"Rebecca", 
"Mitchell", 
'1978-01-23',
"112 South Road",
"Caversham",  
"Dunedin");

-- Insert schools into school table.
TRUNCATE TABLE database_rugby.school;
INSERT INTO database_rugby.school(
schoolName)
VALUES(
"College Street School");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.school(
schoolName)
VALUES(
"Macandrew Intermediate School");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.school(
schoolName)
VALUES(
"Carlton Hill Primary");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.school(
schoolName)
VALUES(
"Caversham Primary School");

INSERT INTO database_rugby.school(
schoolName)
VALUES(
"Concord School");

-- Insert players into player table.
TRUNCATE TABLE database_rugby.player;
INSERT INTO database_rugby.player(
personID, 
schoolID)
VALUES(
    (SELECT personID FROM database_rugby.person 
    WHERE database_rugby.person(firstName) = "Michael" 
    AND database_rugby.person(lastName) = "Peck"), 
    (SELECT schoolID FROM database_rugby.school 
    WHERE database_rugby.school(schoolName) =  "College Street School"));

INSERT INTO database_rugby.player(
personID, 
schoolID)
VALUES(
    (SELECT personID FROM database_rugby.person 
    WHERE database_rugby.person(firstName) = "Matt" 
    AND database_rugby.person(lastName) = "Petersen"), 
    (SELECT schoolID FROM database_rugby.school 
    WHERE database_rugby.school(schoolName) =  "Macandrew Intermediate School"));

INSERT INTO database_rugby.player(
personID, 
schoolID)
VALUES(
    (SELECT personID FROM database_rugby.person 
    WHERE database_rugby.person(firstName) = "Christopher" 
    AND database_rugby.person(lastName) = "Petersen"), 
    (SELECT schoolID FROM database_rugby.school 
    WHERE database_rugby.school(schoolName) =  "College Street School"));

INSERT INTO database_rugby.player(
personID, 
schoolID)
VALUES(
    (SELECT personID FROM database_rugby.person 
    WHERE database_rugby.person(firstName) = "Richard" 
    AND database_rugby.person(lastName) = "Michaels"), 
    (SELECT schoolID FROM database_rugby.school 
    WHERE database_rugby.school(schoolName) =  "College Street School"));

INSERT INTO database_rugby.player(
personID, 
schoolID)
VALUES(
    (SELECT personID FROM database_rugby.person 
    WHERE database_rugby.person(firstName) = "Shaun" 
    AND database_rugby.person(lastName) = "Michaels"), 
    (SELECT schoolID FROM database_rugby.school 
    WHERE database_rugby.school(schoolName) =  "College Street School"));

INSERT INTO database_rugby.player(
personID, 
schoolID)
VALUES(
    (SELECT personID FROM database_rugby.person 
    WHERE database_rugby.person(firstName) = "Harry" 
    AND database_rugby.person(lastName) = "Dackers"), 
    (SELECT schoolID FROM database_rugby.school 
    WHERE database_rugby.school(schoolName) =  "Caversham Primary School"));

INSERT INTO database_rugby.player(
personID, 
schoolID)
VALUES(
    (SELECT personID FROM database_rugby.person 
    WHERE database_rugby.person(firstName) = "Daniel" 
    AND database_rugby.person(lastName) = "Mitchell"), 
    (SELECT schoolID FROM database_rugby.school 
    WHERE database_rugby.school(schoolName) =  "Caversham Primary School"));
```

And here's the output on the MySQL command line interface produced from the two scripts - that will show more information on the errors:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 82
Server version: 5.5.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> source c:\scripts\database_schema.sql
Query OK, 16 rows affected (0.35 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> source c:\scripts\database_data.sql
Database changed
ERROR 1701 (42000): Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constrai
nt (`database_rugby`.`contact`, CONSTRAINT `contact_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person
ID`) REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`person` (`personID`))
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_coach1` FOREIGN KEY (`coa
ch_coachID2`) REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO AC
TION)
ERROR 1701 (42000): Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constrai
nt (`database_rugby`.`player`, CONSTRAINT `player_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`schoolID
`) REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`school` (`schoolID`))
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1701 (42000): Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constrai
nt (`database_rugby`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_player1` FOREIGN KEY (`play
er_playerID2`) REFERENCES `database_rugby`.`player` (`playerID`))
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database_rugby.person does not exist
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database_rugby.person does not exist
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database_rugby.person does not exist
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database_rugby.person does not exist
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database_rugby.person does not exist
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database_rugby.person does not exist
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database_rugby.person does not exist
mysql>
```

And here's the logical model (if anyone sees problems with any of the relationships - in particular, the many:many relationships, please let me know).

[image]

I apologise if I gave too much information, but I thought if I gave all this information it would make things easier on people that want to help me out. I have spent a good 3 hours making adjustments to the DDL script but after spending that long I realised I need someone with more experience to help me. I've showed the logical model to someone with industry experience in databases and they believe it conforms to 3NF. Doing the conceptual and logical models wasn't so bad for myself, it was trying to convert the logical model to working script and successfully inserting data (I want to insert at least 10 records for each table) that has become the biggest hurdle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would strongly suggest you create a **minimal** test-case, i.e. a much simpler arrangement of tables, etc. that still exhibits the same problem.  That way, there's less code for the SO audience to parse and comprehend...

Comment: @Oli - You're quite right there, I just thought that showing the whole script might give people a wider view of the problem. Could you let me know how I can edit this post in a way that would satisfy what you just said? I think having the whole DDL script would be necessary but I think I could trim the DML script for this example. I also supplied an image of the logical model to see if there are any discrepancies there also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add this statement as well
Add it at the top of your dump file

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

This will disable the foreign key checks and you can easily execute the dump file

and add another statement at the bottom of your dump file to enable back the foreign key check

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback - I'll try this first thing in the morning after I've had some sleep, and let you know how it went :).

Comment: Hi Shakti, that line of code appeared to work well, but did not fix the entire problem... Would it be possible for me to have the unique identifier for "Person" to also be the primary key for "Player" in conjunction with the "Player" unique identifier? If so could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The Foreign Key constraints you have between `person` (the Superclass) and `player`, `parent` and `coach` (the Subclasses) are not defining `1:1` relationships. Here is a possible solution:

```
-- Create the "person" table.
--
-- This table has one:one relationships
-- with the parent, coach and player 
-- tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `person` ;                --- no change
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  --- ...
  --- several columns omitted for clarity
  --- ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`personID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The `parent` table can have the `personID` both as Primary and Foreign Key to `person`:

```
-- Create the "parent" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `parent` ;
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  --- `parentID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,             --- removed

  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,

  --- PRIMARY KEY (`parentID`, `personID`),    --- removed

  PRIMARY KEY (`personID`),                    --- this part only as PK
                                               --- which is also a FK
  FOREIGN KEY (`personID`)                     --- as previously (no change here)
    REFERENCES `person` (`personID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And similarly for `player`:

```
-- Create the "school" table.
-- omitted for clarity
--
--    
-- Create the "player" table.
--
-- Inherits fields from the "person"
-- and "school" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `player` ;
CREATE TABLE `player` (
  --- `playerID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,             --- removed
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `schoolID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`personID`),                    --- Primary Key
  FOREIGN KEY (`personID`)                     --- that is also Foreign Key
    REFERENCES `person` (`personID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (`schoolID`)
    REFERENCES `school` (`schoolID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The same should be done to the `coach` table.

---

Note that the above solution allows a `person` to be both a `player` and a `parent` or both a `parent` and a `coach`. If you want to restrict a row of the superclass (`person`) table to be only one the subclass tables, it would have to be a slightly different approach.