# Need some assistance in verifying a database logical schema to Third Normal Form

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, normalization, third-normal-form

This was originally going to be an "update" on the logical schema presented in another question here: [Getting ERROR 1701, ERROR 1452 and ERROR 1305 errors in MySQL - Need some expertise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258515/getting-error-1701-error-1452-and-error-1305-errors-in-mysql-need-some-expert)...

I think I have successfully verified this schema to 1st and 2nd Normal Form, but am unsure if this meets 3rd Normal Form. Here is the model in question:

[image: An attempt on a logical database model to Third Normal Form]

And here is the associated code (note: for some reason I cannot recreate 1:1 relationships in the sql code as illustrated in the logical model above):

```
-- database_schema.sql.
-- This sql script creates the structure.
-- of the rugby club database.

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS database_rugby;

CREATE DATABASE database_rugby;

USE database_rugby;

-- Create the "person" table.
--
-- This table has one:one relationships
-- with the parent, coach and player 
-- tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `person` ;
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `dateOfBirth` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `streetAddress` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
  `suburbAddress` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `cityAddress` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
  `photo` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`personID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- Create the "parent" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `parent` ;
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `parentID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parentID`, `personID`), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`personID`) REFERENCES `person` (`personID`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "school" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `school` ;
CREATE TABLE `school` (
  `schoolID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `schoolName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schoolID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "player" table.
--
-- Inherits fields from the "person"
-- and "school" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `player` ;

CREATE TABLE `player` (
  `playerID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `schoolID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`playerID`, `personID`), 
    FOREIGN KEY (`personID`) 
    REFERENCES `person` (`personID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    FOREIGN KEY (`schoolID`)
    REFERENCES `school` (`schoolID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "coach" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `coach`;
CREATE TABLE `coach`(
  `coachID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `dateBeganCoaching` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`coachID`, `personID`), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`personID`) 
  REFERENCES `person` (`personID`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "family" table.
--
-- This is a linking table 
-- that describes the many:many 
-- relationship between "parent" 
-- and "player" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `family` ;
CREATE TABLE `family` (
  `parentID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `playerID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`playerID` )
    REFERENCES `player` (`playerID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`parentID`)
    REFERENCES `parent` (`parentID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "grade" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `grade`;
CREATE  TABLE `grade`(
  `gradeID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `gradeName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `minWeight` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `maxWeight` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `minAge` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `maxAge` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `ballSize` INT(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gradeID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "coachQualification" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `coachQualification` ;

CREATE TABLE `coachQualification` (
  `qualID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `qualName` CHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  `gradeID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`qualID`) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`gradeID`)
    REFERENCES `grade` (`gradeID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "homePhone" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `homePhone` ;
CREATE TABLE `homePhone` (
  `homePhoneID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `homeNumber` CHAR(9) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`homePhoneID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "mobilePhone" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mobilePhone` ;

CREATE TABLE `mobilePhone` (
  `mobilePhoneID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `mobileNumber` CHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mobilePhoneID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "emailAddress" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `emailAddress` ;

CREATE TABLE `emailAddress` (
  `emailAddressID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `emailAddress` CHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emailAddressID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "Contact" table
--
-- This is a linking table 
-- that describes the many:many 
-- relationships between "person" 
-- and the "homePhone", "mobilePhone", 
-- and "emailAddress" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `contact` ;
CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `personID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `homePhoneID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `mobilePhoneID` INT(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `emailAddressID` INT(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`personID` )
    REFERENCES `person` (`personID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`homePhoneID`)
    REFERENCES `homePhone` (`homePhoneID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`mobilePhoneID`)
    REFERENCES `mobilePhone` (`mobilePhoneID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`emailAddressID`)
    REFERENCES `emailAddress` (`emailAddressID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "qualificationSet" table.
--
-- This is a linking table 
-- that describes the many:many 
-- relationship between "coach" 
-- and "coachQualification" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qualificationSet` ;
CREATE TABLE `qualificationSet` (
  `coachID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `qualID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`coachID`)
    REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`qualID`)
    REFERENCES `coachQualification` (`qualID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "team" table.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `team` ;
CREATE TABLE `team` (
  `teamID` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `teamName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `teamYear` INT(2) NOT NULL ,
  `gradeID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teamID`) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`gradeID`)
    REFERENCES `grade` (`gradeID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "teamAllocation" table
--
-- this is a linking table for a 
-- many:many relationship between
-- team and player tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teamAllocation` ;

CREATE TABLE `teamAllocation` (
  `teamID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `playerID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`teamID` )
    REFERENCES `team` (`teamID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`playerID`)
    REFERENCES `player` (`playerID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- Create the "teamCoachAllocation" table.
--
-- This is a linking table 
-- that describes the many:many 
-- relationship between "coach" 
-- and "team" tables.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teamCoachAllocation` ;
CREATE TABLE `teamCoachAllocation` (
  `coachID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
  `teamID` INT(5) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (`coachID`)
    REFERENCES `coach` (`coachID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`teamID`)
    REFERENCES `team` (`teamID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

From these links below:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

This is my understanding of Normalisation to 3NF:

- First normal form means to not allow repeating values
- Second normal form means 1NF and attributes are dependant on whole primary key and not part of a primary key (I think of this as partitioning tables if values in that table need to relate to eachother in some way and have comparisons made).
- Third normal form means 2NF and no transistive values (e.g if x = y and y = z, x = z)

Putting that knowledge from theory into practice is quite hard for me, especially translating that "practise" into working, normalised MySQL code. If someone is able to help me go through the model and give me some pointers about normalising the model to 3NF, I would appreciate it very much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this isn't in 3NF, around the `contact` table. If I'm wrong this is still a bad way of storing the data and should probably be changed.

Sorry if this is a little confused...

It is entirely possible to have the following structure in your `contact` table as the entire table is the primary key:

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+
| personid | homephoneid | mobilephoneid | emailid |
+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|        1 |           1 |             1 |       1 |
|        1 |           1 |             1 |       2 |
|        1 |           1 |             2 |       3 |
+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+
```

As you can see both `homephoneid` and `mobilephoneid` are duplicated so updating the table `homephone` will result 3 updates to `contact`.

I disagree with the data-model as you *require* a `person` to have a `homehone` I don't have one, only a mobile. In this situation, when creating a new `person` you have to also create a new `contact` and a new `homephone`.

As `contact` is just a primary key and a primary key value cannot be null, you also *require* the creation of a `mobilephone` and an `emailaddress`, which means that `person` is dependent on `emailaddress`.

As `emailaddress` is dependent on `contact`, which in turn is dependent on `person` you've created a circular dependency, which breaks 3NF.

As I see it you have a two options if you want to ensure that people *have* to have a home phone number:

1. If you only want a `person` to have *one* `homephone` then add this
   into the `person` table. It's unique contact level information and
   should be stored there.
2. If you want to enable people to have multiple home phone numbers -
   remembering that multiple people can use the same phone number - but
   don't care about mobiles then you need to create a table
   `personhomephones`, say, with the primary key `personid,
   homephoneid` and not put `homephoneid` in the contact table.

Personally I wouldn't do either of these. I wouldn't ensure that someone has to have a home phone number but instead a primary phone number, where you don't care what type it is. I would allow people to add different methods of contact but allow these not to exist

This would require the following structure:

- `person` - add `primaryPhoneID`
- `primaryphone ( primaryphoneID, phonenumber)` - PK `primaryphoneID`

Then for the contact methods that are allowed to not exist:

- `contactType ( contactTypeID, contactType )` - PK `contactTypeID`
- `contact ( contactID, contactTypeID, value )` - PK `contactID, contactTypeID`
- `personContact ( personID, contactID, contactTypeID )` - PK everything

Whilst this may result in duplication between `contact` and `primaryphone` they are distinct bits of data and I think this is fine. If you're insistent on not allowing any duplication at all you'd have to separate out the phones from the other methods of contact, which makes the model more complicated:

- `phonetype ( phoneTypeId, phoneType )`
- `phone ( phoneID, phoneTypeID, phonenumber)` - PK `phoneID, phoneTypeID`
- `contactPhone ( personID, phoneTypeID, phoneID )` - PK everything

Comment: Cheers for the advice Ben :) I didn't implement exactly what you said but I think I have something that works (I can put up an updated model if need be). My lecturer said something similar to you and I tried to implement something on my own with this advice. I've tested inserts and deletes and so far everything works, once the database is complete I'll put it through some more rigorous testing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [algorithm](http://www.sci.csueastbay.edu/~billard/cs4660/node21.html) to eventually decompose each relation in your schema in order to get an equivalent schema in 3NF. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=3nf%20decomposition%20algorithm&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) is good for that!!

To get tips about your schema design you should at least describe the context and the functional constraints about the entities you need to represent.